# error #1009 in as3 loading webservice

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i'm trying to connect to a webservice through actionscript but i get an error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at wsdlMain()

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
//webservices wsdl
import mx.rpc.soap.*;
import mx.core.*;
import mx.rpc.events.*;

public class wsdlMain extends MovieClip
{
    public var myWebService:WebService; 
    public var rutaWebService:String;
    public var element:Operation;

    public function wsdlMain()
    {   
        myWebService.addEventListener("LOAD", loadDone);
        cargarWSDL();
    }

    public function cargarWSDL (){
        var myWebService = new WebService();

        myWebService.loadWSDL("http://localhost:8080/myTurn/servlet/sequencegenerator?wsdl");
    }

    public function loadDone(evt:LoadEvent)
    {
        trace ("holaaaa222");
        element = Operation(myWebService.getOperation("Execute"));
        element.addEventListener("fault", wsError);
        element.addEventListener("result", wsResult);
        element.send(1);
    }
    public function wsError(evt:FaultEvent)
    {
        trace ("chau");
    }
    public function wsResult(evt:ResultEvent)
    {
        trace ("hola");
        var xml:XML = XML(evt.result);
        trace(xml.toXMLString());
    }


}
}
```

Any orientation will be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add an event listener to myWebService before it exists. Call cargarWSDL(); *before* adding the event listener.

Also, in the function cargarWSDL(), you're declaring myWebService *again* (it's already declared as a class variable), and worse, you're declaring it as a *local* variable which is only visible inside the function, so remove the "var" from "var myWebService = new WebService();".